# Django render_to_string not working on fieldname.help_text

Tags: django, templates

I’m creating an app for a questionnaire and making use of the model fields help_text attribute, which represents the question of each data field.

For this, I wrote some custom model form:

```
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A customized ModelForm for Django.

    This class extends the base ModelForm class from Django's forms module.
    It provides additional functionality to handle errors and help text for form fields.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field in self.errors:
            attrs = self[field].field.widget.attrs
            attrs.setdefault("class", "")
            attrs["class"] += " is-invalid"

        for field in self.fields:
            try:
                self.fields[field].help_text = self._meta.model._meta.get_field(
                    field
                ).help_text
            except Exception:
                pass
```

additionally I created a template tag together with a .html:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("../templates/snippets/radioInlineField.html")
def render_radioInlineInput_field(formfield):
    return {"formfield": formfield}
```

```
{% with field=formfield %}
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-start">
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="mb-0">{{ field.help_text }}: </p>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mt-0 ">
        {% for radio in field %}
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            {{ radio.tag }}
            <label class="form-check-label" for="id_{{ radio.id_for_label }}">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ error }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endwith %}
```

Now everything works good with it, but if I have Form A (only consisting of the above mentioned type of fields) and Form B (which has a required field) on the same view and validation fails for Form B, the `{{ field.help_text }}` is not rendered anymore and I can’t find my problem.

I located it down to this part:

```
def render(
    request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None
):
    """
    Return an HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
    django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
    """
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type, status)
```

where I can see, that my context has still the correct values and include the `form.fields.field.help_text` values after a failed validation, but after it run through the `render_to_string` function the content is missing the `field.help_text` values.

Does anyone have a hint or idea what the problem might be?

- I also tried `field.help_text|safe` same result
- checked that form is passing the correct data to the `render_to_string()` method
- debugged as far as possible

Answer (score 0):

So I gave it another shot and thanks to ChatGPT it pointed me in the right direction. My issue was the order of initilization, corrected version:

```
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""A customized ModelForm for Django.

This class extends the base ModelForm class from Django's forms module.
It provides additional functionality to handle errors and help text for form fields.
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Set field labels from model field help_text before processing errors
    self.set_field_labels()

    # Process form errors to customize field appearance
    self.process_form_errors()

def set_field_labels(self):
    """Set form field labels to the help_text of the corresponding model field."""
    for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
        try:
            help_text = self._meta.model._meta.get_field(field_name).help_text
            if help_text:
                field.help_text = help_text
        except Exception as e:
            # Optionally, log the exception if needed
            pass

def process_form_errors(self):
    """Process form errors to customize field appearance."""
    for field_name in self.errors:
        attrs = self.fields[field_name].widget.attrs
        attrs.setdefault("class", "")
        attrs["class"] += " is-invalid"
```

I still didn't understand it fully, as I don't understand exactly how this makes a difference. So if someone can explain me why this works and my previous code didn't I'd appreciate it much.